# How to get flag attributes from TypedArray?

Tags: android, typed-arrays

I have set multiple flag attributes in an android custom textview, how do I recover the attributes using TypedArray

```
<some.text.view.that.i.defined.TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        font:sanFrancisco="bold|italic"/>


<attr name="fontSanFrancisco">
    <flag name="regular" value="0"/>
    <flag name="bold" value="1"/>
    <flag name="italic" value="2"/>
</attr>

<declare-styleable name="font">
    <attr name="sanFrancisco" format="flag"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**attrs.xml**

```
  <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="font">
        <attr name="my_sampleFlag" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <attr name="my_sampleFlag">
        <flag name="regular" value="0" />
        <flag name="bold" value="1" />
        <flag name="italic" value="2" />
    </attr>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center">
    <com.example.checkstack.MyView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Hello World"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyView**

```
public class MyView extends TextView {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

          TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.font);
            int textStyle = a.getInt(R.styleable.font_my_sampleFlag, 1);
            setTypeface(null, textStyle);
             a.recycle();  
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to set custom font ??

Comment: How to set in attribute through .xml?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
   int style = attrs.getInteger( R.styleable.HighlightedTextView_highlightStyle, -1 );
   if( style >= 0 ) {
        setHighlightStyle( style );
   }
   attrs.recycle();
   }
```

Here is the full [tutorial link](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/custom-controls-part-2/)